# Detect a key event and paste a value in textarea

Tags: angularjs

I have a text area rendered using the following code:

```
<textarea class="input_inline full_width_input" cols="15" id="id_form-0-expected_result" name="form-0-expected_result" placeholder="Expected result" rows="7"></textarea>
```

I use AngularJS and Angular-ui-bootstrap and I want to perform the following action: when a user is typing some text in my text-area : if a user enters '((' then I want to automatically open an Angular UI Modal Box to show him some options. For example:

```
<ul>
    <li>Option 1</li>
    <li>Option 2</li>
    <li>Option 3</li>
</ul>
```

Once the user click on an option (let's say Option 2) I want the modal to be closed and 'Option 2' to be written in the text-area.

Do you have an idea how I can proceed in the most 'Angular Way' ?(I mean without jQuery or other plugins)

Thank you.

Comment: use `ng-model` on textarea and watch that scope variable. Or angular also has key event directives

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KXZVh/) solves the problem. `$scope.$watch` can solve the problem in a pretty straightforward way.

The code looks a bit like;

```
var app = angular.module("App", []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.watchedInput = '';
    var brackets = 0;
    $scope.$watch('watchedInput', function (now, then) {
        if (now && now.length) {
            if (now.charAt(now.length - 1) === '(') {
                brackets++;
            } else {
                brackets = 0;
            }
        }
        if (brackets === 2) {
            console.log('OPEN MODAL');
        }
    });
}]);
```

And the `HTML`

```
<div ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="watchedInput" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I adapt this code to work on multiple textarea? I must create a watch for each watchedInput ?

Comment: @AlexGrs for multiple textareas, I wouldn't `$watch` each one of the models for changes, although thats a bit of an overkill for optimisations. The same can be achieved using directives.